# How to incorporate the validation set in machine learning?

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, training-data

I am trying to learn about machine learning, and I am having trouble understanding when and how to use the validation set. I have understood that it is used to evaluate the candidate models, before checking with the test set, but I don't understand how to properly write it in code. Take for example this code I am working on:

```
# Split the set into train, validation, and test set (70:15:15 for train:valid:test)
X_train, X_rem, y_train, y_rem = train_test_split(X,y, train_size=0.7)          # Split the data in training and remaining set
X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(X_rem,y_rem, test_size=0.5) # Split the remaining data 50/50 into validation and test set

print("Properties (shapes):\nTraining set: {}\nValidation set: {}\nTest set: {}".format(X_train.shape, X_valid.shape, X_test.shape))

import warnings # supress warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# SCALING
std = StandardScaler()
minmax = MinMaxScaler()
rob = RobustScaler()

# Transforming the TRAINING set
X_train_Standard = std.fit_transform(X_train)   # Standardization: each value has mean = 0 and std = 1
X_train_MinMax = minmax.fit_transform(X_train)  # Normalization: each value is between 0 and 1
X_train_Robust = rob.fit_transform(X_train)     # Robust scales each values variance and quartiles (ignores outliers)

# Transforming the TEST set
X_test_Standard = std.fit_transform(X_test)
X_test_MinMax = minmax.fit_transform(X_test)
X_test_Robust = rob.fit_transform(X_test)

# Test scalers for decision tree classifier
treeStd = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, random_state=0).fit(X_train_Standard, y_train)
treeMinMax = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, random_state=0).fit(X_train_MinMax, y_train)
treeRobust = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, random_state=0).fit(X_train_Robust, y_train)
print("Decision tree with standard scaler:\nTraining set score: {:.4f}\nTest set score: {:.4f}\n".format(treeStd.score(X_train_Standard, y_train), treeStd.score(X_test_Standard, y_test)))
print("Decision tree with min/max scaler:\nTraining set score: {:.4f}\nTest set score: {:.4f}\n".format(treeMinMax.score(X_train_MinMax, y_train), treeMinMax.score(X_test_MinMax, y_test)))
print("Decision tree with robust scaler:\nTraining set score: {:.4f}\nTest set score: {:.4f}\n".format(treeRobust.score(X_train_Robust, y_train), treeRobust.score(X_test_Robust, y_test)))

# Now we train our model for different values of `max_depth`, ranging from 1 to 20.

max_depths = range(1, 30)
training_error = []

for max_depth in max_depths:
    model_1 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth)
    model_1.fit(X,y)
    training_error.append(mean_squared_error(y, model_1.predict(X)))


testing_error = []
for max_depth in max_depths:
    model_2 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth)
    model_2.fit(X, y)
    testing_error.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, model_2.predict(X_test)))

plt.plot(max_depths, training_error, color='blue', label='Training error')
plt.plot(max_depths, testing_error, color='green', label='Testing error')
plt.xlabel('Tree depth')
plt.axvline(x=25, color='orange', linestyle='--')
plt.annotate('optimum = 25', xy=(20, 20), color='red')
plt.ylabel('Mean squared error')
plt.title('Hyperparameters tuning', pad=20, size=30)
plt.legend()
```

Where would I run the tests on the validation set? How do I incorporate it into the code?

Comment: Your question is ill-defined; you should first be aware of what exactly is a validation set and how it differs from the test set (which you seem to be already using), before attempting to implement anything in code; but this distinction is not a *programming* question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: In all probability, what you are already using as "test" set is actually your validation one (as also implied by the answer below); the test set is supposed to be used **once and only once** at the end, after we have chosen a final model and in order to get a performance assessment on unseen data. We **never** use the test set twice.

Comment: Irrelevant to your issue, but we **never** `fit_transform` the val/test set - we only `transform` it.

Comment: What exactly did you get from the answer below and you marked is as accepted? That you will do `model.predict()` on the last model of the loop, and from this you will get your test error? Or that you should "*only create one model keep using this one model*"?

Comment: I needed to know when to use the `validation`-set, and the anwer below showed me how to go about it. By first training the training set, and then the validation set. I knew how to use it in practice, but I hadn't seen any examples of it other than in the book im following.

Comment: Suit yourself, but the only (correct) thing in the answer is actually simply the replacement of your `testing_error` with `val_error`, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure to only create one model keep using this one model. Currently you create a model in every training step and overwrite the old one. Otherwise your model will never improve.

Secondly: The Idea behind the validation set is to evaluate the progress of your training, to see how your model performs on data it hasn't seen before. Therefore you need to incorporate it into your training process.

So in your case it would look like that.

```
model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth) # here we create the model we want to use
for max_depth in max_depths:
    model.fit(X_train,y_train) # here we train the model
    training_error.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, model.predict(X_train))) # here we calculate the training error
    val_error.append(mean_squared_error(y_val, model.predict(X_val))) # here we calculate the validation error
test_error = mean_squared_error(y_test, model.predict(X_test)) # here we calculate the test error
```

Make sure that you only train on your training data, never on your validation or test data.

Comment: This is exactly what OP have done for their *test* error.

Comment: Yes and No - But you are right. My answer wasn't correct. I fixed it.

Comment: Still missing; OP trains a whole bunch of models in the loop; which one is supposed to be used for getting the test error?

Comment: He is supposed to only train one model. And evaluate only this ONE model

Comment: How is this apparent in your answer? And why exactly are they supposed to train only one model? (They evidently don't, and with good reason - they are in the stage of model selection...)

Comment: I am afraid that, with each edit, you keep getting the answer worse; "*make sure to only create one model*" does not make any sense (in fact it is plain wrong advice) when one is in the stage of model selection & hyperparameter tuning, as OP evidently is here. Similarly, "*Otherwise your model will never improve*" is also absurd. And your suggested code still does not agree with what you say in your text.